# How do I transfer files from PC to Xbox?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-legacy-console

I only play Minecraft on Xbox, but I am trying to upload maps from my PC to the Xbox. I keep getting stuck as the PC does not recognise the download files as Minecraft is not installed on the PC. Horizon does not recognise the file formats in the downloaded files stored on the PC.

Comment: It might help to provide more description of what you are trying to do to copy the files.  Also, a screenshot of any errors that you are getting would help.

Comment: Thank you. Put simply, I have two zipped folders on my desktop, that contain sub folders with .mca files, screenshots and text files. I don't know which one needs to be uploaded into Horizon. I've tried all of them but one of them work. Having watched the online tutorials, the downloads look fine. Typically they are showing as you need to transfer to the .minecraft app data folder, but i don't have this as minecraft is not installed on the PC.

Comment: Because of the clutter, I want to confirm your question. You want to know how to move a Minecraft map from PC to the Xbox . (Using Horizon?)

Comment: Yes. Although I've seen the tutorials so the process looks simple, so following the instructions is easy, however, each time it banks on the PC having a .minercaft folder in place

Comment: So you're saying that the process requires Minecraft to be installed, but you don't have Minecraft installed? Isn't the solution then to install Minecraft?

Comment: FYI, PC minecraft saves are not directly compatible with the Xbox.  They must be cropped and transformed.  PC minecraft worlds are virtually unlimited in size.  Xbox (360 anyway) are limited in size.  Search for tools by youtuber oPrize.  He has a free and a newer very cheap paid utility that does do PC>Xbox conversions.  And yes, you will need Horizon.  Horizon is the tool that is used to insert files into the USB drive so the xbox will read them as well as extracting them so the PC can read them.  The oPrize utility is what you need to crop and convert a PC save.